# Can we also discuss visual novels, light novels and other related media?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Many anime are derived from visual/light novels, so it only feels natural to also discuss them here. What do you think?

Comment: Original discussion: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/8282/expand-the-scope-to-include-visual-novels-and-light-novels

Answer (score 17):

I think light novels, and other paraphernelia tangential to the "main" anime/manga fandom should be on topic here.

That said, I also believe the site need ***not*** be renamed to enumerate these items' inclusion. Most anime fans I know accept that these things are part of *otaku* culture.

Comment: I agree that a rename is not needed.

Comment: Second for both the inclusion of the media and for the not renaming.

Answer (score 6):

There was a recent discussion on [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7287140#7287140) regarding a question about [Melty Blood](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/507/which-melty-blood-games-are-relevant-plotwise), pertaining relevancy of such games.

In essence it's a family of games which are in various proportions a mix of fighting game genre and Visual Novel - in the "story mode" the VN progresses along a plotline and from time to time duels occur. Now the proportion of fighting to plot varies wildly between those, and the asker wanted to know the order in which to play to follow the storyline of Tsukihime.

The consensus on Chat was that questions about that kind of games are relevant only if they ask about (or depend strictly on) the plot aspects of the game. Questions that pertain to the game mechanics, multiplayer, and other elements that are not directly relevant to the VN part are better asked on Arquade.

(in particular, the question about order is on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

I think that I will cite Madare Uchiha's response to this question: [Are live-action series based on anime/manga/light novels on topic here?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/are-live-action-series-based-on-anime-manga-light-novels-on-topic-here). I think that only anime and manga should be discussed on this site, though questions about comparisons between light novels and their corresponding anime/manga, for example, should be allowed. That draws a pretty solid line.

Comment: What is there about Manga that makes light novels not be suitable? Same goes for visual novels. They're all very closely related Japanese media, so I don't think we should keep half of it out.

Comment: +1 - We already *have* a site for VNs and similar, and that's Arqade. There's also the fact that they are produced outside of Japan, while anime isn't.

Comment: @MartinSojka: Eh, they originate from Japan and are vastly more popular there than anywhere else. Also, I don't think that VNs quite fit to Arqade. And even if we leave VNs out, what about light novels?

Comment: @Xeo: There already *are* VN questions on Arqade, and though they aren't common, they're still welcome there. An example would be [Analogue: A Hate Story](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82018/what-is-the-full-list-of-log-entries-in-analogue-a-hate-story), which also happens to be created by a Canadian, [Christina Love](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christine_Love_%28visual_novelist%29).

Answer (score -3):

I think this SE should probably be renamed to something so that all mediums of otaku culture are included, not just visual novels.

There are light novels, vocaloid, doujinshi, etc. that would all serve well on one site since the demographics for these are very similar.

Comment: Agreed, I also have a few of the "Twelve Kingdoms" novels laying around. I would certainly like to be able to discuss them in here.

Comment: I agree with this too, the demographics are indeed overlapping enough.

Comment: While I agree on the suggested scope, I don't think renaming the site is necessary.

Comment: I dont know why this was voted down, seems a pretty reasonable thing. I actually feel this too, because when I just started out, I wasnt sure if VNs were on topic. (At least it should be made more obvious from the site)