# What should our FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion

We should start thinking about the FAQ for the site.

Some of the points I think we should agree on:

- What kinds of questions are good on-topic questions on this site?
- Where is the line drawn between on-topic and off-topic?

Probably there are more, we should discuss.

Answer (score 6):

I'll post my views here. I'll be fixing the answer if new issues come up.

- Same as on Movies SE, I think we should forbid questions about **future** releases. So anything like:

  > Will there be an Anime for this Manga?
  >   When will this Manga volume be published?
  >   *and so on...*

  They are Not constructive as they invite for speculation.

Answer (score 4):

Importing some conclusions from [Can we also discuss Visual Novels, Light Novels and other related media?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/can-we-also-discuss-visual-novels-light-novels-and-other-related-media)

To be added to on-topic list:

- Visual novels, light novels, and other tangentially related media (e.g. drama CDs) to the "main" anime/manga fandom

Possibly within a separate point:

- Fighting, shooters, and similar games derivative from common Anime/Manga franchise:
- Plot-centric questions related to events described in these games and how they fit in the plotline of the franchise are on-topic
- Questions about game mechanics, technical, and other aspects not related to the plot of these games belong in [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This... for some reason many SE communities forget to include their off/on-topic rules in their FAQs.

Answer (score 3):

I think we should include a faq on how to use the spoiler markup in the faq or somewhere more accessible for new users, as anime contains a lot of spoilers and many new users don't use the advanced help link when creating a question.

Just looking for a better way to inform users about the markup, otherwise this will be the main job for moderaters, implementing spoiler markup for questions by new users.

Answer (score 2):

> **Disclaimer**: This answer is Community Wiki so feel free to add, fix, change, etc. When we see it's completed, we'll use this as our FAQ.

**Spoiler**: In order to insert spoilers in your question, write your spoiler as a blockquote, but adding an exclamation mark, like `>!`. Every line with these symbols will be hidden until you hover with your cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be specified in the FAQ what exactly we are accepting as anime/manga. For example, it should be made clear that there are certain criteria that make something fit under the category of anime or manga. For anime, [How is anime defined?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157/how-is-anime-defined) has some good answers, and while one hasn't been specifically chosen yet by the person asking, they generally have the same idea that the definition should be based on origin.

Answer (score 0):

How to [cite sources](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/191/98) for real world questions and in-universe questions; a list of reliable sources we can trust and use as reference, i.e. to check if [a work is or it's not an anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/69/98); a suggestion (not a strict rule) to adopt a neutral cultural perspective when [making a question](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/what-should-be-the-cultural-perspective-of-anime-and-manga-se) to avoid endless discussions about definitions. This should be implemented by [asking author of the question](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/206/98) to reformulate his/her question and not by rewriting.

Answer (score -1):

Two things the FAQ should add:

- **Recommendation charts:** Based on popularity, genre and demographic. There are many examples ([this](http://images.wikia.com/animu-mango/images/8/89/1266460057179.jpg) and [this](http://images.wikia.com/animu-mango/images/7/70/1262839877207.jpg)) that allow people to see some wide variety of titles before asking what to watch.
- **Season X tag:** Mainly to avoid getting a lot of new tags, maybe having a specific tag per season would allow people to find about new shows that are currently airing.

This two small things would help a lot to filter repetitive posts or maybe issues for new shows.

Comment: Actually, it's exactly the place to propose it. That's the purpose of this question. People post answers based on what they think the faq should contain, and people vote on it. @Logan

Comment: @MadaraUchiha You're right that this is the right place to post this; I misinterpreted the question (I blame Christmas). However, my downvote still stands. I don't think we should be in the business of recommending anime, whether it's on the FAQ or the main site, and especially not with something as unprofessional as a 4chan chart. I'd be less opposed to linking to something that's more professional-looking and democratic, e.g. ANN's top 50 list: http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/ratings-anime.php?top50=best_bayesian

Comment: @LoganM That chart was just an example, there are several sites that contain this type of charts or recommendations. I just quote that as an example, because it contains many mainstream anime titles in several categories and in different times which may give more options than charts based on ratings.