# Do anime style movies made out of Japan (and Asia in general) belong?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is anime defined?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157/how-is-anime-defined)

Do anime style movies made out of Japan (and Asia in general) belong?

In particular, does [Wakfu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wakfu#Animated_series) (made in France) count as anime, or is it just stylized anime-like western animation? Does it belong here at all?

Comment: I think that's a big part of this question http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/157/how-is-anime-defined