# Are graphic novels on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

In terms of audience, graphic novels appear to be on-topic. Most any store I go to to buy manga will have graphic novels nearby. That said, it will also likely share a wall or a storefront with Marvel and so forth.

- How should scope be defined around graphic novels?
- Is the limiting factor the presentation style or culture-based?
- What is the difference between graphic novels and manga in terms of audience, and does that matter to scoping the site?

Comment: How are Graphic Novels defined?

Comment: @SF.That is the point of the question for me. Some Graphic Novels will be very much from the style of an anthology of collected, serialized Western style comics (see Wipqozn's answer), whereas others (see Chirale's answer) will refer to a different scope. A useful answer to this question will help to define what a graphic novel actually is, and how it does/n't fit into the knowledge base of this community

Answer (score 5):

No, graphic novels should not be on-topic. Comics such as Watchmen, Batman, Bone, et cetera are *not* manga, and should thus be ruled off-topic. See this related meta here: [How should manga be defined?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-should-manga-be-defined)

Comment: I am not talking about serialized comics. By graphic novel I would be referring to the works of novels like Jimmy Corrigan, Black Hole, Ed the Happy Clown and works that do not exist in the canon you appear to be referring to

Answer (score 1):

Jiro Taniguchi and [Moebius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Giraud) (a French artist recently passed away) worked together to make *[Icare](http://www.nonsolomanga.it/manga4/taniguchi_icaro.htm)*. This can be called a graphic novel *and* a manga and this is absolutely on-topic. Not all graphics novels are Western comics, there are even important collaborations from a Japanese artist and a Western artist like this.

Agreeing to a [by origin definition](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/266/98) or a by [external reference definition](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/189/98) (here about anime) will solve this question, because excluding graphic novels will be ambiguous as ambiguous is the definition of "graphic novels": a more "literary" and appealing term for comics or manga, but not a term to distinguish between manga (Japanese comics) and comics (Western comics).

In answering this question, graphic novels should not be excluded because many manga could be defined as graphic novels.

Comment: We would just have to be careful if we go with what you're saying to make it clear that only graphic novels that count as manga by other agreed on definitions are allowed. We can't allow all graphic novels indiscriminately just because some are manga.

Comment: We can't allow the usage of the term "graphic novel" in any rule, because it's too vague. Manga in the first place is not a style, is the Japanese term for "comics". Graphic novel are another term for comics (and, trust me, there are many comics artists that ridicule this term because it's self-celebrating or worst) but without the origin constraint that "manga" has in the Western usage of the term. So, here, it's not a useful term, only a troublesome one.