# Are live-action series based on anime/manga/light novels on topic here?

Tags: discussion

Several anime series have been made into live action series in Japan, Taiwan, Korea, and elsewhere. Are these on topic for here?

Examples include:

- For You In Full Blossom (aka *Hana Kimi*) -- TW, JP, KR
- Boys Over Flowers (aka *Hanadan* or *Hana Yori Dango*) -- TW (as *Meteor Garden*), JP (twice!), KR
- Gokusen! -- JP
- Honey and Clover -- JP
- Perfect Girl Evolution (aka *Yamato Nadeshiko Shichi na Henge!*) -- JP
- Detective Conan -- JP
- Maoh (aka *Demon*) -- JP
- GTO (aka *Great Teacher Oniizuka!*) -- JP
- Bishoujo Senshi Seira Muun (aka *Sailor Moon* or *Pretty Guardian Sailor Moon*) -- JP
- Glass Mask -- JP

Comment: For those unaware: KR == Korea, JP == Japan, TW == Taiwan. These are *just* the version I know about. There are also versions in PH (from the Philippines), VN (Vietnam) and TL (Thailand).

Answer (score 14):

I'd argue we should only accept questions on the Anime/Manga versions. And not the later versions where it became live action series-es.

Simply because we need to draw the line somewhere, or there'll be no ends to it.

As for comparisons between the Anime version and the live action version, I think we'll generally *allow* it, though the line is rather thin. We'll allow because it **does** deal with the original anime as well as the live action.

Comment: That's fair. How about questions comparing the two? As in, "What are the differences between YamaNade manga and the live action?"

Comment: @Aarthi: Good one. I guess that one would be very individual. I think we'll generally accept those, because they do deal with the original Anime/Manga. Much like if Naruto would make a real action movie, we'd be able to somewhat ask questions about it, as long as it's in the scope of the original series.

Comment: Excellent! Would you mind adding that corollary to your answer?

Comment: @Aarthi: Added. Now lets wait for community support, I wouldn't want my opinion to pass without others thinking the same.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much.