# Do live actions based in anime questions belongs to Anime SE?

Tags: discussion

Do live actions based in anime belongs to Anime SE or they are for another SE community? If so, which would it would be Sci Fi and Fantasy SE? Movies SE?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "live actions"?  Do you mean live-action interpretations of anime works?

Comment: Live action movies. Yes, live-action interpretations of anime works

Comment: ie Ghost in the Shell, but that wasnt the case

Comment: Anyway, I posted it in Sci Fi SE and they liked that kind of questions being posted there. I dont know if that is content which overlaps with Anime SE, or it is just better fit in there.

Comment: There's definitely some overlap.  I think it can find a home in both places, but I'll want to write something more formal up when I can get a bit more quiet time.

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate of https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13, but my understanding is that was superseded by https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415, which would suggest that such questions about live-action adaptations of anime/manga would be allowed. However very few such questions have been asked, and most of them are about comparing the live-action adaptation to the original work.

Comment: What I wanted to ask (that I already did in Sci Fi SE and got the answer so no point reposting it here I guess) it was this question . https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/164075/how-many-times-has-the-in-production-robotech-live-action-movie-changed-director . Here there is also a rule against asking about "production details" or something like that, so it still dubious if that question was allowed here. And for that old question about expanding scope of questions, Anime has as much fans as Sci Fi in real world or more. There must be a reason why Sci Fi SE has more users than Anime SE

Comment: ... I have 2 theories why Sci Fi SE has much more users than Anime SE. 1) Sci Fi is more "mature" and since the showcase of both communities is stackoverflow.com with old mature  people with a lot of culture they tend to go more to Sci Fi (I have serious doubts Sci Fi and Fantasy content in general is more mature than Anime so dont quote me on this theory) and theory 2) Anime SE is too restrictive in its questions .