# Should we create a death-note movie tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, allowed-topics

With the recent *Death Note* Netflix movie (and potential second movie coming), I was wondering, should we create a separate tag for it considering the plot diverges a lot from the original series?

As for if it's considered on-topic to begin with: it seems to be considered somewhat on topic:

- [Are live-action series based on anime/manga/light novels on topic here?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17/1458)
- [What topics outside of anime and manga can I ask about?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2535/what-topics-outside-of-anime-and-manga-can-i-ask-about?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [What is our current stance on questions about peripheral anime topics?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2380/1458)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I say yes. It's not diverging very far from the anime version and we are pretty much the place to ask about plot details and in-universe explanations. Also we could gain some activity in these hard times when nobody has any other questions :p